# npm install local folder only installs node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I want to install a local project by using "file:../project-name" in the package.json. However, when I run this command it only installs the dependencies of the local project (node_modules) and not the source files itself.

I have project-name/src for example and I expect it to appear in node_modules/project-name/src, but it doesn't.

I checked the .gitignore (I don't have a .npmignore file) and src as a folder is not excluded.

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [files property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files), this does not indicate files to copy to the node_modules on npm install, but it indicates the files to publish on npm publish.

**Edit**

When including a dependency with file:... in a project, the directory has to:

1. have a package.json
2. Declare exported files in the "files" property.

Comment: file:../project-name was what I put into my dependencies. However, you pointed my into the right direction. The files where not installed because I did not put them into the files property... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Reading the documentation again I noticed that my first answer wasn't correct. But glad it helped anyway !